# use xsl:param to select attribute in xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to output 2 attributes of a kind of element.
I'd like to use only 1 template with one parameter to reduce code.

XML is like :

```
<myElement attribute1="x" attribute2="y" />
```

I'd like to call templates like this :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement">
   <xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="@attribute1" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement">
  <xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="@attribute2" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Problem is in the definition of the template :

```
<xsl:template match="myElement">
  <xsl:param name="paramAttr"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$paramAttr" /> <!-- NOT ACCEPTED -->

</xsl:template>
```

I tried different things like introducing @ at different places, with concat() or {} without much success.
Any idea ? thank you.

Comment: At least for the reduced snippet where the template does nothing but outputting the attribute value I wonder why you can't simply write a template matching the attributes e.g. `<xsl:template match="myElement/@*"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>` and use `<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@*"/>` (or if order matters `<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@attribute1, myElement/@attribute2"/>` in XSLT 2/3 or spelled out `<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@attribute1"/><xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@attribute2"/>` in XSLT 1)?

Comment: You are completely correct.
Your feedback has helped me finding another solution : <xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@attribute1"/> is as short and valid too.
In fact, I could not see how to define the template itself but <xsl:apply-templates select="myElement/@attribute1" mode="jsList" /> and <xsl:template match="@*" mode="jsList" /> makes the job.
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the attribute name as a string:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="myElement">
   <xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="'attribute1'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and select the attribute based on its name in the called template:

```
<xsl:template match="myElement">
  <xsl:param name="paramAttr"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $paramAttr]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what problem occurred with your current approach but I think it results from the rule on how `xsl:with-param` is evaluated, if you look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#element-with-param it says

> The current node and current node list used for computing the value
>   specified by xsl:with-param element is the same as that used for the
>   xsl:apply-templates or xsl:call-template element within which it
>   occurs

respectively XSLT 3 defines in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-with-param that

> The focus used for computing the value specified by the xsl:with-param
>   element is the same as that used for its parent instruction.

That means, if the outer context/focus of your `xsl:apply-templates` has a `myElement` child you select for the `apply-templates`, in the `xsl:with-param` you need to use `<xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="myElement/@attribute1`"/>, as the `xsl:apply-templates` doesn't change the context/focus for its inner `xsl:with-param`. Of course using a variable with e.g.

```
 <xsl:variable name="el" select="myElement"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$el">
    <xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="$el/@attribute1"/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
```

can make that approach shorter and more readable. If there are several `myElement` elements then it is better to change the context/focus either with

```
<xsl:for-each select="myElement">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
    <xsl:with-param name="paramAttr" select="@attribute1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or to first push the `myElement` element to a template where you then further process the attributes.